# Angular: Unable to select default option in cascaded dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="defaultFirstMenu" ng-options="item as item.menuName for item in firstLevelList"></select>


<select class="form-control" ng-model="defaultSecondMenu" ng-options="item as item.menuName for item in (filteredSecondLevelList = (secondLevelList | filter:{parent: defaultFirstMenu.menuName}))" ng-init="defaultSecondMenu = filteredSecondLevelList[0]"></select>
```

The options are getting populated in second dropdown, but ng-init is unable to set default option.
**defaultFirstMenu** is not declared before. Please help.

Comment: can you provide controller code?

Comment: add `ng-if='defaultFirstMenu'` in second select

Comment: @MichaelColeman controller just contains data of **firstLevelList** & **secondLevelList**

Comment: @entre this didn't work!

Comment: @Shreyas didnt work means what? can you setup a plunker with dummy data

Comment: @entre a fiddle with another example is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qowp9qzz/2/)